# sorting an array and then going through it

Tags: php, arrays, sorting

I have an array like, for example this:

```
$fruits = array("lemon", "orange", "banana");
```

if I print_r this I get:

```
[0] lemon
[1] orange
[2] banana
```

I want to sort this alphabetically and then print them going through the array, so I did:

```
sort($all_venues);
$i = 0;
$results = 0;
if ( isset($_GET['filter1']) && isset($_GET['filter2']) ) {
    while ($i < count($all_venues) ) {
        if (in_array($f1, $venues[$i]) && in_array($f2, $venues[$i])) {
            echo '&diams;  <a href="'.$venues[$i]['url'].'" target="main">'.$venues[$i]['name'].'</a> ';
            $results++;
        }
        $i++;
        if ( $i == count($all_venues) ) {
            if ( $results == 0 )
                echo '<i>no venues matching your filters</i>';
            else
                echo ' &diams;';
        }
    }       
} else {
    while ($i < count($all_venues) ) {
        if (in_array($f1, $venues[$i])) {
            echo '&diams;  <a href="'.$venues[$i]['url'].'" target="main">'.$venues[$i]['name'].'</a> ';
        }
        $i++;
        if ( $i == count($all_venues) )
            echo ' &diams;';
    }
}
unset($i);
```

how come If I print_r the array after the sort I see what I expect (banana, lemon, orange) but the while loop does not echo them in the correct order?

Comment: Post your *actual* code. What you've given us there is an infinite loop and there's *no* guarantee that `$i` will start at zero.

Comment: You are incrementing `$i` outside while loop!!

Comment: ok sorry guys... I know you have to initialize $i and that it needs to be inside the loop... I wrote this code hastily to avoid throwing my actual code in here out of context... I apologize... sooooo I've updated the question with my actual code since it was too long to add here... sorry guys

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### Edit

Your code is printing out the wrong data/information because you're sorting `$all_venues` but printing from `$venues`.

---

#### You're creating an infinite loop...

But let's start with the first issue.

You're `echo`'ing `$fruit` instead of your actual array: `$fruits`.

---

Second issue, you're incrementing `$i` outside of your loop....so that never ever iterates through the array. You never defined the variable either. What you want is this:

```
$i = 0;
while($i < count($fruits)) {
    echo $fruits[$i];
    $i++;
}
```

Which returns: `bananalemonorange`

[**Example/Demo**](https://eval.in/579790)

Comment: Mmm, bananalemonorange, the perfect storm of fruity goodness. Though, when I first read it, I saw "banal menagerie" which reminded me of my work colleagues a couple of jobs ago :-)

Comment: @paxdiablo especially when you eat it in that order ;-)

Comment: Its fine that its a simple fix. But let the OP try to find out the issue with his code. If we give answer for small fixes, then beginners fail to think of their own. We may need to bring out answer from him

Comment: @Thamilan He was on the way there, yet because of the infinite loop, no effective errors would've been produced for said OP. I guarantee that he'll never hit this error again, because he now understands what was causing it to not work (Thanks to the answer). Remember, we all gotta start somewhere ;-)

Comment: thanks guys, I'm stupid but not that stupid ;-) please see my edit

Comment: @marcnyc Updated answer!

Comment: @marcnyc Pleasure :-) Glad it helped you out!

Answer (score 0):

I guess you need [asort()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.asort.php)

```
$fruits = array("lemon", "orange", "banana");
asort($fruits);
foreach($fruits as $fruit){
    echo $fruit;
}
//bananalemonorange
```

---

Read more about [Sorting Arrays](http://php.net/manual/en/array.sorting.php)

Comment: do `asort($all_venues)` before the first `while`